# What can you deduce from my performance in different types of chess tactics?

Tags: tactics

So each day I practice a different tactic.  So my tactics training regimen is like this (Chess Tempo)

Day 1:

5 problems - (standard) specific tactical motif (i.e. discovered attack, sacrifice, fork/double attack, etc)

5 problems - blitz

5 problems - mixed

Day 2:

5 problems - (standard) specific mate type

5 problems - "problems I've gotten wrong at least once"

5 problems - standard

And I alternate everyday doing that.  I keep a log to record how well I am doing.  If over three consecutive runs of the same tactic, I end up scoring a 13 (out of 15) or better, I will up the difficulty by 200 points (right now I have all the specific tactic-type sets limited to 1400-1700).  My Chess Tempo standard tactics rating is around 1600.

Right now, I am not even done with one round, but so far I have this:

Advanced Pawn   5

Attraction  3
Avoiding Perpetual  2

Avoiding Stalemate  3

Back Rank Mate  3

Blocking    4

Capturing Defender  2

Clearance   2

Coercion    3

Counting    3

Defensive Move  1

Desperado   3

Discovered Attack   3

Distraction 4

Double Check    2

Exposed King    4

Mate - Anastasia's  3

Mate - Balestra's   1

Mate - Arabian  5

Mate - Backburne's  5

Mate - Boden's  4

Mate - Damiano's    5

Mate - Damiano's Bishop 4

Mate - Double Bishop    5

Mate - Dovetail 4

Mate - Dovetail - Bishop    4

Mate - Epaulette    3

Mate - Escalator    3

Mate - Greco's  3

What can you deduce from my performance in various tactics types, in terms of my strengths and weaknesses as a player (tactically)?

Comment: Not much. Keep working on the things you're less good at.

Comment: I deduce that you tend to overthink things ...

Comment: lol @BlindKungFuMaster  I've been told this so much in the context of dating from various people online and in real life.  I really do.  I thought I would be overthinking things in chess.  lol now someone is even calling me out for overthinking in chess...lol...what am I?  What exactly indicates that I overthink things from this post?  I overthink, mainly because I feel I have to to survive.

Comment: @R3dder Pick up the book 'Think and Grow Rich' by Napoleon Hill - it will eliminate it.

Comment: Nothing as you meant the question. And your approach to learning is poor.

Answer (score 2):

Chess tactics frame different positions which we sometimes come across the Board . It may be Double attack , fork , Pin and many others . Just solving the Chess tactics lone is never the measurement because when you solve a tactic you know already that there is a sacrificial or a combinational move which will make you win or help to solve the tactic . In real games sometimes you even get an easy position but you fail to find the best move OTB .

Solving tactics just make you at ease that you are doing something and practicing Chess but it is never the complete homework to make the best judgement .

A different way to find the performance measurement is that how good you are making a calculation or even finding your own weaknesses in specific patterns . like for an example you have a habit of leaving your piece hanging in your own games . So you must solve tactics relating to Hanging pieces which will help to improve your weak point . They say in whichever tactic you find it difficult to solve you have a weakness in that area .